# Setting Timer Interval to Infinite

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, timer

I have a method that links a *BO* `Connection.AliveInterval` to a `System.Timers.Timer` (.NET **2**).

Some connections are managed to be always connected.

Is it OK to set in such a case

```
if (myConnection.AliveInterval == Connection.TimeInfinite)
{
    myTimer.Interval = double.PositiveInfinity;
}
```

?

Should I expect that the Timer will throw exceptions or rises ever the Elapsed event ?

Comment: @Oded: Once connection established, counting connection time.

Comment: So, to see if a connection has timed out?

Comment: @serhio: I think you'd better apologise...

Comment: @Oded: You can't read minds, but read the code `if myConnection.AliveInterval == Connection.TimeInfinite myTimer.Interval = double.PositiveInfinity;` this is not the real code, I modified it to be self explanatory.

Comment: @serhio - Strange apology. Still calling my questions stupid.

Comment: I have to say it, I don't get how the OP can act with any ounce of superiority given the question / just run it ... extremely quick thing to do ... omg, just saw that last comment come in "I consider your querstion stupid", oh the irony ...

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you are referring to the somewhat misleading information I get in a yellow tooltip in MonoDevelop and VS when using the constructor of a `System.Timers.Timer`:

> Set the value to *Infinite* milliseconds to disable periodic signaling.

You get this information for a parameter with the type `Int32`, `UInt32` or `TimeSpan`. Somewhat surprisingly, these types do not provide a property named `Infinite`.

You want to use a `Timeout.Infinite` in order to get the desired result.

Note that the *online* reference discribes it correctly:

> Specify *Timeout.Infinite* to prevent the timer from starting.

**Edit**: I just realized that this will not work for the setter, only for the constructor of the timer. So your best bet is probably to use `myTimer.Stop()`, as suggested by @spender or `myTimer.Enabled = false` as commented by @Bolu.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `myTimer.Stop()`?

Comment: because this is not an action, but an initialization. And I didn't Start()

Comment: @Bolu. Maybe... however, what about the `Interval`?

Comment: In the context of your question that is lacking in the necessary information to offer better informed help, I think it is probably your style of question that is not useful. You're burning your bridges by such arrogant behaviour. If I'd picked up this question and had a chance to observe your "community spirit", I wouldn't bother answering.

Comment: based on MSDN:The value must be greater than zero, and less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue.

Comment: To quote MSDN: "Setting Enabled to true is the same as calling Start, while setting Enabled to false is the same as calling Stop.". Your response to @Bolu is inconsistent with your response to me.

Comment: @spender: Once Connected, the timer.`Start` (or Enabled=true) will be called. So, there is no sense to set enabled to false(or Stop).

Answer (score -1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx):

> The value must be greater than zero,
>   and less than or equal to
>   Int32.MaxValue
>
> An `ArgumentException` will be thrown,
>   when the interval is greater than
>   Int32.MaxValue, **and** the timer is
>   currently enabled. If the timer is
>   not currently enabled, no exception is
>   thrown until it becomes enabled.

So, the `PositiveInfinity` will throw an exception, if the simer will be enabled.

Now, a solution would be to disable the timer and set the value to `PositiveInfinity`. When Enabling the Timer, catch `ArgumentException` and ceck the Interval to `PositiveInfinity`.